# Why an image view shows up after an audio is played whereas the image's visibility is set to true before the audio is played in javafx?

Tags: javafx

I've been trying to get my hands on JavaFx. I have an issue which I can't solve on my own. On my scene there is a play button which is supposed play an mp3 file. The mp3 should start playing after a gif image shows up on the scene but for some unknown reason to me it is the other way round: first the audio is played then the gif shows up.

The code looks more or less like this in the controller (a simplified version. 
I omitted the code that could blur things:

```
    public void buttonClicked(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws MalformedURLException {

            Button bt = (Button) actionEvent.getSource();

            switch (bt.getId()) {
              case "btPlay":
                 Optional<Randomize> firstResult = luckyNumbers.stream().filter(s -> s.getAnswerWasCorrect().equals(false)).findAny();


                    if (firstResult.isPresent()) {
                        showSoundWave(); //this method gets the image to be seen. 
                        playLuckyNumbers(firstResult.get().getRandomLong()); // this method plays the audio

                    } else {
                        luckyNumbers.clear();
                        Alert newAlert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
                        newAlert.setHeaderText("We've run out of numbers");
                        newAlert.show();
                        btStart.setDisable(false);
                        groupedPlayRepeatButtons.setDisable(false);

                    } 
              break;
            }

}
```

Here's the code that gets the image to be seen when the play button is clicked:

```
 private void showSoundWave() {

            imgSound.setVisible(true);

            FadeTransition ft = new FadeTransition();
            ft.setNode(imgSound);
            ft.setFromValue(1.0);
            ft.setToValue(0);
            ft.setDuration(Duration.millis(5000));
            ft.setCycleCount(1);
            ft.play();
        }
```

When I remove the line with the code that play the audio (playLuckyNumbers method) the image behaves like expected. Can anyone help and provide a sample code?

Comment: I believe the animation runs in the background. Your program is not paused for five seconds, waiting for the animation to terminate. Hence method `playLuckyNumbers()` is invoked before the animation completes.

Comment: Both playing animations and playing media are asynchronous operations. This means the calls to `play` return immediately. If you want play some media after an animation completes then use the `Animation#setOnFinished` callback.

Comment: Slaw, I don't want to play the animation and then the media. I want them to play almost simultanously. In fact the final solution is to work that way that mp3 file's length will set the duration of the animation and the animation will be seen as long as the audio is playing. That's what I want to achieve but my understanding of the subject fails me.

Comment: Ah, that wasn't clear to me. If you want the animation and media to play near-simultaneously then that should be doable with a simple `player.play(); animation.play();`. I'm still not exactly sure on what the problem is, however. Are the two things not playing simultaneously at all or is there an unacceptable delay or is it something else? I also think you should [edit] your question to provide a [mre] (← read linked page); though you've attempted to minimize the code you've done so to the detriment of completeness which makes it hard to fully understand the flow of execution.

Comment: And a tip for using this site: [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work).

Comment: @Slaw, here's the link to an mp4 file with a recording of how you it works when you press the button which is supposed to make the gif visible and right after it an audio is played [link] (https://drive.google.com/open?id=1LHGsKqblEk9DxXjEbGOnUhMYONIu21LD). As far the code it is enough to see  the methods showSoundWave() and playLuckyNumbers(). I had already provided the former. As for the latter it makes sense just to show you this because the rest is business logic:

Comment: `List<String> filteredList = list.stream().filter(s->s.contains("mp3"))    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            filteredList.forEach(s->{
                try {
                    audioClip = new AudioClip(new File(s).toURI().toURL().toString());
                        audioClip.play();
                        while (audioClip.isPlaying()) { //Wait until the clip has finished playing
                        }
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });`

Comment: Your `while (audioClip.isPlaying())` is the culprit, I believe. This causes the _JavaFX Application Thread_ to spin wait, which in effect is the same thing as blocking said thread. Though the animation API is asynchronous it still uses the FX thread which means while the FX thread is blocked the animation updates cannot happen; in fact, your entire GUI should be frozen while spin waiting in the `while` loop (may not be noticeable if the audio is very short).

Comment: @Slaw, thanks for the clue. It might be it. In fact I play several audio files one after the other. I'll turn them into one file and see how it goes. I'll check it out and let know if my problem has been solved